# When to use "-que" and when to use "et"?

Tags: conjunction

For example, it is "*Senatus Populusque Romanus*" but it could be "*Senatus et Populus Romanus*".

Similarly, it is "*qui ex Patre Filioque procedit*" but it could be "*qui ex Patre et Filio procedit*"

Perhaps more drastically, in the [*Tantum Ergo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantum_Ergo) we read:

```
Genitori, Genitoque
Laus et iubilatio,
Salus, honor, virtus quoque
Sit et benedictio:
Procedenti ab utroque
```

Basically, one line uses "-que" and the next one uses "et".

Is there any **fundamental** reason why one method is preferred than another? The [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-que#Latin) for "-que" states that:

> In archaic and official language, **-que** is preferred to **et**, from which it is distinguished by denoting a closer connection.

Is that what explains the above examples? That might be clear in the case of "SPQR" and the [Nicean Credo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filioque) (where the *filioque* is sometimes found). But it is not so evident to me in the case of the *Tantum Ergo*. Maybe there is more to it? Is there a "canonical" answer to this issue, or is in the end essentially arbitrary, perhaps based on taste, rhymes, etc?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that no-one knows the real reason for joining the *-que* to a preceding noun, but I believe that something similar occurs in ancient Greek (of which I know almost nothing).

I'm inclined go along with the explanation which I was taught: that Roman manuscripts were written without a break between words, and that subsequent redactors, knowing or believing that no break was observable in speech, treated the *-que* as an enclitic when separating the words.

I suspect that there are other enclitics used in the same way, e.g. in *egomet* and *tutemet*, but I know of no authority for that.

The different usages such as *et, -que, ac,* etc. depend on both style and context — sometimes, the word formed can 'look' wrong,or grate on the ear — making it hard to give a rule agreed by all authorities. To my ear, *senatus populusque romanus* sounds better than the alternative with *et*. For poetry, the metre may well determine the choice.

Comment: It looks as if the question was altered while I was answering it (including a part about using _que_ as a separate word, which explains why my second paragraph is there). Ought the answer to be deleted, or shall I allow it to stay?

Comment: From what I've seen on other sites, there's no reason to delete a correct answer, even if the question is a duplicate (or bad, or whatever). I say leave it.